# (Django) Sharing authentication across two sites that are on different domains

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have two sites say foo.com and bar.com and are both Django based. Primary registration occurs on foo.com (I'd like the main user db to be here) and I'd like for three things to happen:

1) User that logs in to foo.com is automatically able to access bar.com without logging in again

2) User that logs in to bar.com directly is authenticated against foo.com user db.

3) There is no need for a user to register at bar.com directly.

How can I achieve this? If it greatly simplifies things I can make bar.com a subdomain of foo.com (eg. bar.foo.com) but they must be separate sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 3rd requirement could easily be solved by sharing the same database between the two sites (therefore having the same Users table.

The 1st requirement is tricky because of cross domain issues (the session cookie will not be shared).

What you are really looking for is a [Single Sign On (SSO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).  You might consider [django-openid](http://simonwillison.net/2007/Apr/24/openidconsumer/).

Comment: #2 can be done a couple of ways: direct access to the other database, or by using a server<=>server chat.

As John said, #1 is the main problem.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your requirements.  If you're able to, the simple solution is to simply host both sites on one Django instance.  In other words, your Django project hosts both sites but you have a url [rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) that maps `foo.com` to `http://localhost/foo/` and `bar.com` to `http://localhost/bar/`.  Django's auth system will "just work" under this scenario.  Rewrite rules can of course also apply to subdomains; I've built a system that hosts hundreds of subdomains using this technique.

If this isn't an option, sharing databases between your Django instances and setting `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`, as mentioned by others, should work.

Comment: Um, why the down vote?  This is a perfectly natural way to handle subdomains or domains that all share the same data.

Comment: Your potential solution certainly does not warrant a downvote.

Comment: No idea why this would be down voted, but this looks like a pretty good answer to the question and seems to be exactly what I needed. Hopefully this works with nginx in front of the django project...

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar problem but OpenID was not a viable solution for me. With the advent of multiple databases in django >1.2, it is now pretty easy to share session and login data across sites. [This blog post](https://gist.github.com/dustinfarris/6085132) does a great job of explaining how to get it set up. Hopefully others find this as useful as I did.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` setting.  You would set it like this:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'foo.com'
```

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#session-cookie-domain for more information on that.  This does assume that both applications are using the same session storage backend.

Answer (score 0):

These can be achieved by implementing [CAS (Centralized Authentication Service)](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/central-authentication-service/).

In your example, foo.com is your server, bar.com is the client. Only one server is required; you can have as many clients as you need.

On your server:

- Install and configure [django-mama-cas](https://django-mama-cas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) (or any equivalent) and [django-cas-ng](https://djangocas.dev/docs/latest/install.html) (or any equivalent).
- Not required to add *django-cas-ng* urls on the server.

On you client(s):

- Install and configure [django-cas-ng](https://djangocas.dev/docs/latest/install.html) (or any equivalent).
- Add the login and logout *django-cas-ng* urls on the client's urls.py.
- For me, I have added the decorator @login_required(login_url="/accounts/login") to the protected views
- Be sure to define CAS_SERVER_URL in the settings.py of the client. In your example, that would be something like "CAS_SERVER_URL = foo.com".

Hope this helps someone as I have not found any tutorial that explicitly gave and explained the instructions above.