# Login cross first-level domain in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to enable cross domain login in my django site, but I'm using  first-level/top-level domain, i.e mysite.fr, mysite.en, mysite.uk...

I've tried something like that SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'mysite.' but it don't works.

Any help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is share cookies between domains. Can be done by setting a cookie on one of your domains and checking for that cookie from another or synchronizing cookies between your domains (server-side).

Similar questions on StackOverflow:

- Using [django-openid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581620/1431750)
- [How do I use cookies across two different domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315132/how-do-i-use-cookies-across-two-different-domains)
- [What's your favorite cross domain cookie sharing approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263010/whats-your-favorite-cross-domain-cookie-sharing-approach)

Others:

- Using [OpenID](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2010/mar/02/simple-sign-openid/) as a SSO to manage common logins
- [From example #3 on this page](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/article.php/c19417/Sharing-Cookies-Across-Domains.htm)
- Here's an [interesting presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/SlexAxton/breaking-the-cross-domain-barrier) on how to do this with different tools.
- [This one](http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/) does it in PHP

Comment: thanks aneroid, I will review the links you've suggested me...and back to you if... ;-)